# how to implement OTP for a transaction

Tags: android, sqlite, one-time-password

I'm using android studio and SQLite db. I want to implement OTP in my application. There is a **sender** and a **receiver** user. **Receiver** will generate otp and give it to **sender**. Then the **sender** will use this otp to send funds.

Now I'm able to generate otp using random number generator, I want to make this otp be valid for say 5mins and in that time if the **sender** makes transaction then it is okay otherwise otp will become invalid and transaction will fail. How to do this? Is it possible with SQLite db? I have **transactions** table which has **otp** as one of its column. Till now I'm only have the following code to generate otp. Someone help me with the further code.

otp generating code from **receiver** in **MainActivity**-

```
public int generateOTP(int maxNumber,int minNumber){
  Random r=new Random();
  int randomNumber = r.nextInt((maxNumber-minNumber)+1)+minNumber;
  return randomNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an extra column say **otpissued** used store the time of the transaction along with the OTP and then check this was within the time-frame.

The sender of the request would not be given the time or supply it other than it being the current time thus there is no way to circumvent the check (unless the sender could manipulate the time on the device with the database).

e.g. The following is the transactions table:-

[image]

Using :-

```
`INSERT INTO transactions VALUES(null,1234, julianday('now'));`
```

- Note **`1234`** is used for demonstration purposes it would be the generated pass code

Would add a row.

For demonstration rows could be shown using

- `SELECT id, otp, otpissued, strftime('Addded on %Y-%m-%d at %H:%M:%S',otpissued) AS issued_date_time FROM transactions;`
- This just makes the date the transaction more human readable.

So the transactions table could be :-

[image: ADD IMAGE 1 HERE]

- Actual table would be :
- [image]

The transaction could be checked using :-

```
-- Check if the transaction is valid no row = timed out 1 row = valid
SELECT id,
        CASE WHEN julianday('now') >= otpissued 
            AND julianday('now') <= julianday(otpissued,'+5 minutes') 
        THEN 'VALID' 
        ELSE 'INVALID'
    END AS validation,
    -- Used for testing/demonstation
            otp,
            strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %S',julianday('now')) AS current_date_time, -- FOR TESTING/DEMO
            strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %S',otpissued) AS otp_date_time, -- FOR TESTING/DEMO
            strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %S',otpissued, '+5 minutes') AS otp_expiry , -- FOR TESTING/DEMO
            julianday(otpissued) AS issued_jd, -- FOR TESTING/DEMO
            julianday(otpissued,'+5 minutes') as expiry_jd -- FOR TESTING/DEMO
    -- End of additional columns for testing/demonstration
    FROM transactions
    WHERE otp = 1234 
    --Alternative will output no rows if invalid (outside time-frame) 1 or more rows if valid (within time-frame)
    --WHERE otp = 1234 AND (julianday('now') >= otpissued AND julianday('now') <= julianday(otpissued,'+5 minutes'));
```

Which could would result in (expired as over 5 minutes) :-

[image]

Of course the above Check would be :-

```
SELECT id,
        CASE WHEN otp = 1234 
            AND julianday('now') >= otpissued 
            AND julianday('now') <= julianday(otpissued,'+5 minutes') 
        THEN 'VALID' 
        ELSE 'INVALID'
    END AS validation
    FROM transactions
    WHERE otp = 1234;
```

In which case the result would be (or empty if no transactions met the WHERE criteria i.e. had the correct otp):-

If a new row is added :-
[image]

#### Testing Valid

(*Note you'd likely not have the same **OTP** and likely also be more selective such as use the transaction id so you'd only get 1 row to check, but this is a demo*)

[image]

Then the long winded check would result in :-

[image]

The compact check would be :-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's better to implement an [RFC6238](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6238) also known as Time-Based One-Time Password in order to get proper OTP implementation.

Also, Random is not the best way to receive one-time passwords in terms of security.